# How do I put multiple values in an array while foreaching through values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Alright so I'm trying to adjust an array and decode it to json, currently it decodes the array like this;

```
{"campaignId":"18210f12-502c-4d71-a098-4f595304a8d0","fields.CPLastName":"Voornaam 1","fields.CPFirstname":"Achternaam 1","fields.OROrganisation":"Bedrijf 1"}
{"campaignId":"18210f12-502c-4d71-a098-4f595304a8d0","fields.CPLastName":"Voornaam 2","fields.CPFirstname":"Achternaam 2","fields.OROrganisation":"Bedrijf 2"}
```

Code:

```
$request = array();
foreach($address_data as $address) {
    foreach($address as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'campaignId') {
            $request[$key] = $value;
        }

        if (strpos($key, 'fields') !== false) {
            $fields = explode('.', $key);

            $request['fields'] = array(
                array('fieldId' => $fields[1], 'value' => $value)
            );
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($request);
}
```

What I want to do is, where it says; fields. I want to explode on that and replace fields. with fieldId within a fields array. So something like this;

```
$request['fields'] = array(array('fieldId' => $key, 'value' => $value));
```

Now for some reason it will only do the last key, and I want it to loop through all the keys where it says 'fields.'

So the final request should look something like;

```
{   
    "campaignId":"18210f12-502c-4d71-a098-4f595304a8d0",
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId":"CPLastName",
            "value":"Voornaam 1"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": "CPFirstname",
            "value": "Achternaam 1"
        },
        {
            "fieldId":"OROrganisation",
            "value":"Bedrijf 1"
        }
    ]
}

{   
    "campaignId":"18210f12-502c-4d71-a098-4f595304a8d0",
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId":"CPLastName",
            "value":"Voornaam 2"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": "CPFirstname",
            "value": "Achternaam 2"
        },
        {
            "fieldId":"OROrganisation",
            "value":"Bedrijf 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don’t see you using `explode` anywhere in what you have currently shown. Please show the actual _code_ of what you have tried, instead of just vaguely and ambiguously _describing_ what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have just updated the code with the right one.

Comment: It still all makes rather little sense. You are using the `campaignId` as key on the outermost array level here - but the desired result you have shown does not use any such keys. You would need a normal, continuously numerically indexed array starting with 0 to get that kind of result with json_encode in the first place.

Comment: `$request['fields'] = array(...` - this is the issue, you don't increment or add to it, rather overwrite it every time, could do something like; `$request['fields'][] = array(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary helper variable in cases like this, that you assemble the array data structure for a single item in.

Add that temp array to the result array at the end of the outer loop.

```
$request = [];
foreach($address_data as $address) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach($address as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'campaignId') {
            $temp[$key] = $value;
        }
        if (strpos($key, 'fields') !== false) { // === 0 would perhaps make more sense here
            $fields = explode('.', $key);

            $temp['fields'][] = [
                'fieldId' => $fields[1],
                'value' => $value
            ];
        }
    }
   $request[] = $temp;
}

echo json_encode($request);
```